# Ember.js - afterRender fires before CSS is finished

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'd like to show a loading symbol while my validation is processing. My .hbs file looks like this

```html
<div {{bind-attr class='isProcessing:spinner'}}></div>
```

I tried to wrap my validations into the afterRender run loop, but apparently afterRender doesn't mean after-CSS. My validations are executed before the css class of the div changes (It doesn't change at all).

```js
App.PostController = Em.Controller.extend({

    isProcessing: false,

    actions: {

        savePost: function() {

            this.set('isProcessing', true);

            Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, function() {

                // do a lot of validating and other (non-asynchronous) stuff here
                // ... this may take several seconds

                this.set('isProcessing', false);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

What can I do that my code starts to execute after all CSS rendering is done?

I also tried Ember.run.next. This doesn't work either. Ember.run.later works with a timeout of at least about 200ms but of course I don't want to hardcode any static timespan.

**UPDATE:** Here is a js-fiddle for my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/4vp2mxr0/2/

Any help would be apprechiated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you wrapping your async stuff in `Ember.run.scheduleOnce` at all? This is not necessary. You only need to make sure that the `isProcessing` property is set to `false` once the async operations are finished but there is no need to delay this.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Unfortunately my validations are **not** async. Ember seems to update the class-binding only after everything (synchronous work) is done

Comment: No, Ember will update any computed property immediately once its value changes. But you need to declare it as a computed property. Please see [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/) how to do this.

Comment: A class-binding is a computed property, or not? And how can I make that isProcessing is a computed property? I don't want it to be computed, I want to set it by myself. My understanding is that Ember updates computed properties immediately ('sync'-queue), but finishes my function ('actions'-queue) before it re-renders/applies content- or class-bindings the template ('render'-queue). That's because I try to wrap it into the run loop. I updated my question with a js-fiddle, hopefully this will clarify the situation. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please wrap your code in [Ember.run.next](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html#method_next). Like this:

```
savePost: function() {

    this.set('isProcessing', true);
    Em.run.next(this, function() {
        //just some synchronous code that takes some time (the time inbetween the two alerts)
        var i=0,a;
        alert('start code');
        while (i++ < 10000000) {
            a = Math.pow(i, Math.pow(1/i, Math.sin(i)))/3/4/5/5 * Math.log(i);
        }
        this.set('isProcessing', false);
        alert('finished code');
    }); 
}
```

[It works as intended.](http://jsfiddle.net/4vp2mxr0/3/) I think your problem is that you set `isProcessing` to `true` and then immediately set it to `false`, because you don't wait for async code/promises to complete. In this case you have to set `isProcessing` to false when promises are resolved. If this is only one promise you can set `isProcessing` to `false` inside `.then()`, for example:

```
myModel.get('children').then (children) =>
  @set 'isProcessing', false
```

Or if you resolve multiple promises, or you resolve promises inside a loop, you can use [Ember.run.debounce](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html#method_debounce) which will fire after XXXms after last call to this method, for example:

```
finishProcessing: ->
  @set 'isProcessing', false

actions:
  savePost: ->
    myModel.get('children').then (children) =>
      children.forEach (child) =>
        child.then (resolvedChild) =>
          Ember.run.debounce @, 'finishProcessing', 500
```